# play/pause Audio on Mousedown/up with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I am trying to use jQuery to dynamically assign listeners to anchors to play sound on mousedown and pause on mouseup. Here's my html:

```
<p>Meet 
  <a class="easter-egg">Buck
    <audio class="egg-aud" src="file.mp3">
      <source src="file.ogg" />
    </audio>
    <img class="egg-img" alt="" src="file.jpg" />
  </a>.
</p>
```

And my js:

```
$( "a.easter-egg" ).mousedown( function() {
  $( this ).find( "audio.egg-aud" )[0].play();
});

$( "a.easter-egg" ).mouseup( function() {
  var audio = $( this ).find( "audio.egg-aud" )[0];
  audio.pause();
  audio.currentTime = 0;
});
```

EDIT: In jsfiddle my code works perfectly until I wrap the `<p>` in a `<div class="entry-content">`, at which point it breaks. I pasted a sample of my website into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronfuzion/u3LZr/1/), where you can try deleting the div and see that it works without it.

Comment: I've put this into a JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/25Ksg/. An alert before the mousedown callback code works for me.

Comment: Hmmm yes it does. actually the sound works too, but only if i paste in that one paragraph. if i paste in my whole page it breaks. Thanks I'll be over there troubleshooting

Comment: To clarify, I pasted my code to jsfiddle with full urls

Comment: When you say you can access the anchors and audios, do you mean from the console?

Comment: no what i mean is the following in my code before the function: `alert( $( "a.easter-egg" ).html() );` and `alert( $( "a.easter-egg > audio.egg-aud" ).html() );` both showed me what i expected. but i have determined that the code works. for some reason it works until the paragraph is wrapped in `<div class="entry-content">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaaand right after I went to bed I realized the problem. I recently wrote a script that changes the text of each instance of an author's name into a link to their list of posts. To do this it replaces the contents of each p element with a new string, which means it recreates the anchors and audios that I'm working with. So ill i guess ill just have to make sure that happens first.

Comment: "On" that you said you used should take care of elements that are not there at the time of binding. As long as the container that you attach the "on" handler to is present.

Comment: That's good to know, but in that case I would have to attach the handler to paragraphs instead of anchors. The problem was easily fixed by simply moving my mouse listeners after my html rewrite in my script

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem:

You were trying to set `currentTime` of audio tag that has been appended dynamically. Thus, you have to wait for audio tag to be ready to play.

#### Solution:

Check whether the audio element is ready to be played using the [`canplay`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#event-media-canplay) event.

```
// When the audio element "can"be"play"ed, fire the function.
audio.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
   this.currentTime = 0;        
},true);
```

#### Comments:

1. Previously, the error you had been getting in the console was:
   "Error: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable."
   Do keep checking the errors, they are very useful :)
2. The same thing applies for `<video>` tags that have been appended dynamically.

#### [Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/gesotoze/1/edit)

Hope that helps !

Comment: I didn't add the audio dynamically, it's just part of a wordpress post's content. Also, I copied my code to jsfiddle on AlexB's recommendation and it works over there.

Comment: @Aaronfuzion I just noticed. :( Forget this answer.

Comment: In fact, I did add the audio dynamically, but not how we were thinking, haha! See my answer